# Laravel - Pull Details from Another Model based On Select Option

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, select, laravel-5

I was curious to know if it was possible to pull details from a separate table on a create form.

For example, if I had a variety of fields, and one was a drop down with a list of users, I'd like a div of their details (from fields within the table) to show up underneath the select option based on my choice from the dropdown.

I'm assuming it's possible through AJAX but I'm not entirely sure with it being a create form and all.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

### Update

A portion of the html/php related to the select box

```
 <div class="box-body">

                <select name="bill_to" required class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:100%;" id="bill_to" onchange="invoicedue(event);">
     <option></option>
     @foreach($customers as $customer)
     <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer->customer_name }}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select> 
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function billtodetails(e){
    $('#bill_to').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/customers/customerDetails',
            data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=bill_to]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Successfully added Origin!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                       $('#existing_biller_details').append(
                           '<p>'+data['customer_name']+'</p><p>'+data['billing_address_1']+'</p>';
                        );
                    }
                },
            });
        });
});

</script>
```

Edited Version based on comment suggestions:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#bill_to').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/customers/customerDetails',
            data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=bill_to]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Successfully added Origin!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                       $('#existing_biller_details').append(
                           '<p>'+data['customer_name']+'</p><p>'+data['billing_address_1']+'</p>';
                        );
                    }
                },
            });
        });
});

</script>
```

Update with working script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#bill_to').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/customers/customerDetails',
            data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=bill_to]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Changed Bill To!'+data.customer_name, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                       $('#existing_biller_details').append(
                           '<p>'+data.customer_name+'</p><p>'+data.billing_address_1 +'</p>');

                    }
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                      alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  } else {
                      alert('Unexpected error.');
                  }
                }
            });
        });
});

</script>
```

Return from response payload:

```
[[{"id":3,"company_name":"Power Equipment Company","first_name":"","last_name":"","account_type":1,"shipping_address_1":"","shipping_address_2":"","shipping_city":"","shipping_state":"","shipping_zipcode":"","billing_address_1":"","billing_address_2":"","billing_city":"","billing_state":"","billing_zipcode":"","primary_phone":"","primary_fax":"","old_account_number":"","website":"","created_at":"2017-11-20 19:41:52","updated_at":"2017-11-20 19:41:52","customer_name":"Power Equipment Company","origin":null,"primary_email":null,"created_by":0}]]
```

Comment: Yes you can use an event on a form control to trigger an ajax request and send whatever data needed from the form to get whatever is needed

Comment: @charlietfl - it looks like it's trying to submit my whole form, rather than just the select button I was referring to. Do you have an suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Not without a [mcve]. I assumed you meant `<select>` which should not submit a form by itself

Comment: @charlietfl - I've added some portions which deal with the select specifically. Does the .change work for this select and where might the POST be going wrong? I will note that it is in a POST form along with a couple dozen other fields.

Comment: Get rid of the `onclick` in the html and unwrap `$('#bill_to').change` from the function and put that inside `$(function(){ /* code here */})` instead. You are effectively adding a new change handler every time the `onclick` function is called and it won't do anything the first time since the event already occurred

Comment: I've made the suggestions and added them above, do they look correct? I've also edited my select to: <select name="bill_to" required class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:100%;" id="bill_to">

Comment: Should be making the request now,  no?

Comment: @charlietfl - it isn't as of now, I did a quick test to make sure it was doing something with the command on change by substituting the code with an alert instead:<script>
$(function(){
    $('#bill_to').change(function() {
        alert("Your book is overdue.");        });
});
        
</script>

Comment: Now the alert code worked, which means it does fire based on the change in the selections, but when I replace it back with the above ajax request, I see nothing that shows it is even trying to post.

Comment: Add an error handler to the `$.ajax` and also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Can see every part of a request there

Comment: Alright, I got the post to work using your suggestions, so I thank you a great deal for all of your help. I was curious, before I add the answer with respect to your comments and suggestions, if you had an idea as to why my append section was not returning an data. I keep getting the values as undefined, rather than the return values. I have included both the updated script as well as an example json return where the undefined labels popped up where the field's data was supposed to be returned. Thanks!

Comment: Add `dataType:'json'` to the $.ajax config object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments below the question from user @charlietfl (a great thank-you to him), the script was corrected to provide error reporting and pull data from the report, though focused as a GET request rather than a POST request, as well as adding the dataType per the suggestion in the last comment.

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $('#bill_to').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',


    url: '/customers/customerDetails',
dataType:'json',
                data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=bill_to]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Changed Bill To!'+data.customer_name, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                       $('#existing_biller_details').append(
                           '<p>'+data.customer_name+'</p><p>'+data.billing_address_1 +'</p>');

                    }
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                      alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  } else {
                      alert('Unexpected error.');
                  }
                }
            });
        });
});

</script>
```